# Cannot read property Score

Tags: angular

I am trying to iterate through JSON data

```js
var Source = [{
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 34,
    "Score": 12
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 4,
    "Score": 132
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 3,
    "Score": 5
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 24,
    "Score": 120
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 1,
    "Score": 56
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 7,
    "Score": 7
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 14,
    "Score": 5
  }
];

var newData = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < Source.length; i++) {
  if (Source[i].Score === 5) {
    var nexIndx = i + 1;
    if (Source[nexIndx].Score == 120) {
      newData.push(Source[i], Source[nexIndx]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(newData);
```

I want the users to be able to search vertically
Example
Manchester United Scored 12 goals in League1
The following Season They scored 132.
In the third season, they scored 5 goals,
Then 120 goals in the fourth season

```html
<div>
<input type="number" placeholder="Any season">
</div>
<h5>Next Season</h5>
<div>
<input type="number" placeholder="The Next season">
</div>
<div>
<button (click)="FindVertical"> Search
</button>
</div>
```

I want the user to be able to filter a season and the next season

Comment: try `<button (click)="FindVertical()"> Search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic array overflow issue. You loop over an array, getting the value after the current value to compare it to. Only when you get to the last value, there is no entry after that, so `Source[nexIndx]` is `undefined`.

The solution is either to stop one earlier by not executing this code for the last element, or to start one later (`i = 0` becomes `i = 1`) and look backwards instead of forwards. I show the latter below:

```js
var Source = [{
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 34,
    "Score": 12
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 4,
    "Score": 132
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 3,
    "Score": 5
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 24,
    "Score": 120
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 1,
    "Score": 56
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 7,
    "Score": 7
  },
  {
    "Name": "Man U",
    "Games": 14,
    "Score": 5
  }
];

var newData = [];
var i;
for (i = 1; i < Source.length; i++) {
  if (Source[i - 1].Score === 5) {
    if (Source[i].Score == 120) {
      newData.push(Source[i - 1], Source[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

first your code is not getting user input on the html page. So you need to define your input variables:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="season1" type="number" placeholder="Any season">
    <input name="season2" type="number" placeholder="The Next season">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div>Season1: {{score1}}</div>
<div>Season2: {{score2}}</div>
```

then, in order to read vertically the scores, all you need is this:

```
const form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('#myform');
var score1 = 0;
var score2 = 0;

form.onsubmit = () => {
  const formData = new FormData(form);

  let s1= formData.get('season1') as int;
  let s2= formData.get('season2') as int;

  score1 = Source[s1]["Score"]
  score2 = Source[s2]["Score"]

  return false; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You got that error due to `newIndx` value.

In your array the last element is `{"Name": "Man U", "Games": 14, "Score": 5}` means your 6th element, After that your are increase your index position means `6+1 is 7` is your new position. You're trying here like `source[7].source === 120` so that it returns `Cannot read property Score`.

And one more thing is you're push your value in array whenever match your score is 120. You can replace your loop with below one.

```
for (i = 0; i < Source.length; i++) {
  if (Source[i].Score == 120) {
    newData.push(Source[i], Source[i]);
  }
}
```